# Search for motif in protein sequence?

Tags: perl

I have written the following script to search for a motif(substring) in a protein sequences(strings). I am beginner and writing this has been tough for me. I have two questions regarding the same:
**1. Errors: The following script has few errors. I have been at it for quite sometime now but have not figured out what and why?**
2. The following script has been written to search for one motif(substring) in protein sequences(strings). My next task involves searching for multiple motifs in a specific order (ex: motif1 motif2 motif 3 motif4 this order cannot be changed) in the same protein sequences(strings)

```
        use strict;
        use warnings;

        my @file_data=();
        my $motif ='';
        my $protein_seq='';
        my $h= '[VLIM]';   
        my $s= '[AG]';
        my $x= '[ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV]';
        my $regexp = "($h){4}D($x){4}D"; #motif to be searched is hhhhDxxxxD
        my @locations=();

        @file_data= get_file_data("seq.txt");

        $protein_seq= extract_sequence(@file_data); 

    #searching for a motif hhhhDxxxxD in each protein sequence in the give file

        foreach my $line(@file_data){
        if ($motif=~ /$regexp/){
        print "found motif \n\n";
        }
        else {
        print "not found \n\n";
        }
        }
#recording the location/position of motif to be outputed

        @locations= match_position($regexp,$seq);
        if (@locations){ 
        print "Searching for motifs $regexp \n";
        print "Catalytic site is at location:\n";
        }
        else{
        print "motif not found \n\n";
        }
        exit;

        sub get_file_data{
        my ($filename)=@_;
        use strict;
        use warnings;
        my $sequence='';

        foreach my $line(@file_data){

        if ($line=~ /^\s*$/){
        next;
                }
        elsif ($line=~ /^\s*#/){
        next;
        }
        elsif ($line=~ /^>/){
        next;
        }
        else {
        $sequence.=$line;
        }
        }
        $sequence=~ s/\s//g;
        return $sequence;
        }

        sub(match_positions) {
        my ($regexp, $sequence)=@_;
        use strict;
        my @position=();
        while ($sequence=~ /$regexp/ig){
        push (@position, $-[0]);
        }
        return @position;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all, the keyword is `elsif`, second of all you don't need it. You can compress the code in the `get_file_data` loop to:

   ```
   next if $line =~ /^\s*$|^>/; 
   $sequence .= $line;
   ```

   As long as you're going to use regular expressions -- unless too unwieldy -- you might as well search for all the cases that you want to ignore. If you find that actual second case, you can add it as an another *alternation*. Say you wanted to exclude lines that begin with `#-`. Then you would just add it in like so: `/^\s*$|^>|^#-/`
2. Another thing is that `my position=();` needs to have the `@` sigil, before position, or otherwise, perl thinks you're trying to something tricky with a call to `position()`.
3. You need the following changes:

   ```
    my $h= '[VLIM]';   
    my $s= '[AG]';
    my $x= '[ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV]';
   ```

   Otherwise, you're just assigning to `$h` to an array reference with a single slot populated by whatever would be returned from the *sub* `VLIM`.
4. Third, don't use `$&`. Replace `pos($sequence)-length($&)+1`

   ```
   push @positions, $-[0];
   ```

   or better yet, use [English](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar):

   ```
   use English qw<-no_match_vars>;
   ...
   push @positions, $LAST_MATCH_START[0];
   ```
5. I would suggest the following for the file reading:

   ```
   use IO::File;
   ...
   # Use real file handles
   my $fh = IO::File->new( "<seq.txt" );
   get_file_data( $fh ); # They can be passed
   ...
   sub get_file_data{
       my $file_handle = shift; 
       ...
       # while loop conserves resources
       while ( my $line = <$file_handle> ) { 
           next if $line =~ /^\s*$|^>/;
           $sequence .= $line;
       }
   ```
6. A suggestion for going forward -- it helps me immensely:

   A. Install [Smart::Comments](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart::Comments)

   B. Put this at the top of your script:

   ```
    use Smart::Comments;
   ```

   C. Every time you're not sure what you've got so far, like if you wanted to see the current contents of `$sequence`, place the following in the code:

   ```
   ### $sequence
   exit 0;
   ```

   just show it and exit. When you get too many printouts, delete them.

Answer (score 0):

- Use "elsif" instead of "elseif".
- Are @file_data and @fasta_file_data supposed to be the same thing?

In `match_positions`:

- Remove the parenthesis around the sub name.
- Change "my position" to "my @position".
- Change the pattern from /regexp/ig to /$regexp/ig.

Comment: @Nathan Kitchen: changes made

Comment: I don't think they should be. @fasta... holds the lines from the input, but the other holds the other lines. 

You seem to passing get_file_data the name of the file, but then just jumping to the point where you've read it into an array. Please see my #5, for how to make that a reality.